# GET request to API

Tags: python, api, python-requests

I am trying to make a GET request to a specific api.

```
import requests
import json

access_token = "71e89e8af02206575b3b4ae80bf35b6386fe3085af3d4085cbc7b43505084482"
url_base = "https://api.huntflow.ru/"

headers = {
  'User-Agent': 'App/1.0',
  'Host': 'api.huntflow.ru',
  'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  'Accept': '*/*',
  'Authorization': 'Bearer {0}'.format(access_token)
}

def test():
url = '{0}me'.format(url_base)

response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)

if response.status_code == 200:
    return json.loads(response.content.decode('utf-8'))
else:
    return response.json()


print(test())
```

Output: 
    {'errors': [{'type': 'oauth', 'value': ['bad_authorization']}], 'description': 'Invalid access token'}

What could be the matter, tell me?

Comment: Your token might have expired, generate a new one and try again.

Comment: might be an invalid access token

Comment: https://github.com/huntflow/api/blob/master/en/errors.md seems to descrbe this, maybe authorize yourself again?  https://github.com/huntflow/api/blob/master/en/authorization.md looks relevant

Comment: Are you absolutely sure that access token is correct?  How did you get it?

Comment: @JohnGordon the employer sent me and claims that everything is ok. Very strange, is everything ok with the script?

Comment: I don't see any obvious errors in the script.  But there are some details that _could_ be wrong.  For example, you're accessing the `/me` url -- is that correct?  I don't know.